# Get text from select with ng-repeat (select2 autocomplete)

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Select2 library for autocomplete(directive name) with angularjs single-page. But I have a trouble with get the text of selected option:

```
<!--$scope.testData = [{code:1, value:'Test1'}, {code:2, value:'Test2'}];-->
<select id="test" name="test" ng-model="test" autocomplete> 
  <option ng-repeat="obj in testData" value="{{obj.code}}">{{obj.value}}</option> 
</select>
```

I'm using ng-repeat instead of ng-options because select2 plugin doesn't have support for that.

At this part I got the value of obj.code and save it on $scope.test, but, additionaly I need to save in a other variable the text of obj.value selected. How can I do this? Basically this is because I need to print in another step that value (not code) but I too need save the code.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to watch the `test` value (or ng-change if that's supported) and when it changes loop through your testData to find the object with the same code and then update your other variable for display.

Alternatively you could use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) which lets you set `test` to be the object then you can display the value or code as you need.